# Create editable spreadsheet-like table in Django site

Tags: html, css, django

I am making a planning site that uses a spreadsheet-like table where every day is a row and every school subject is a column. The table rows are all the days of a year and the columns are all the school subjects.

[image]

The table cells have to be editable and stylable, so you can add and remove and highlight homework. Basicallly just like google spreadsheets. You have to be able to instantly edit the cell upon clicking on it.

These edits have to be saved to a database, so that other users can follow along with the edits. But how can I save everything onedit to the database?

How can I create this spreadsheet functionality in a Django website?

I already tried html tables with contenteditable. Or should I use input forms?

Could anyone provide with an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way, and actually standard approach, to doing such things would be to split your app on frontend and backend, use Django for the backend part and some js framework (React, Vue.js and so on) for the frontend part. Add Django-rest-framework API to the backend to communicate between the parts. There are plenty of examples to start with.

But recently I came across this [github repo django-funky-sheets](https://github.com/trco/django-funky-sheets), something genius, in my opinion. A little bit hacky way to use the js library [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) with Django :) Maybe not very effective, but a possible solution for little projects. The repo is outdated and no longer supported, still you can do a fork and work on PRs.